# Ruby regex returning unmodified string?

Tags: regex, ruby

New to this but I am trying to make a redirect using Ruby and Regex:

Old link: https://blog.example.io/eng/2020/01/29/post-title

New desired link: https://example.io/blog/post-title

Here is the code I am using:

```
re = /https:\/\/blog\.(example\.io)(?:\/eng\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})?\/(.+)/
str = 'https://blog.example.io/eng/2018/02/21/post-title'
subst = 'https://$1/blog/$2'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)
```

But it is returning:

```
https://blog.example.io/eng/2018/02/21/post-title
```

How do I produce: "https://example.io/blog/post-title"?

***Edit***

Using the modified regex I was provided:

```
/https:\/\/blog\.(.*?)(?:\/eng\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})?\/(.+)/
```

I am now able to return "https://$1/blog/$2". Is there a reason $1 and $2 are not being replaced by "example.io" and "post-title"?

Comment: Your regexp matches `blog.example.com`, not `blog.example.io`

Comment: Good catch @Barmar, I've updated the question as this was a typo.

Comment: You need to state the rules for going from one string to another. For example, do you wish to remove `'blog.'` if it appears anywhere, if it appears after `'\\'` and/or before `'example.io'`, or do you wish to remove whatever dot-terminated string that follows `'\\'`, such as `'\\cat.'`, and so on.

Comment: You need to use the block form of `#gsub` if you want to use the global `$1`, `$2`, ...: ["In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, ... will be set appropriately."](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Comment: @pldfs : Maybe unrelated, but I feel that in your case, a regex is overkill.  You could simply do a `result="https://example.io/blog/#{File.basename(str)}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern seems slightly off.  Consider using this version, which does not make any assumptions about the domain and extension:

```regex
https:\/\/blog\.(.*?)(?:\/eng\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})?\/(.+)
```

Then, keep your replacement the same.  [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ib6BpG/1) to see the updated pattern working.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen. This returns "http://$1/blog/$2" so I think I am getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

Your repacement pattern is wrong, the regex pattern has no issue.

The fixed Ruby code is

```rb
re = /https:\/\/blog\.(example\.io)(?:\/eng\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})?\/(.+)/
str = 'h'+'ttps://blog.example.io/eng/2018/02/21/post-title'
subst = 'https://\1/blog/\2'
result = str.gsub(re, subst)
p result
```

See the [online Ruby code](https://ideone.com/sZYoea).

If you need to match any hostname, use

```rb
re = /https:\/\/blog\.([^\/]+)(?:\/eng\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})?\/(.+)/
```